# How to represent SQL table format in Redis Format for querying purpose?

Tags: database, redis

I read many web articles and guides about Redis, which have great informations, but I can't find all my wandering. Since I am new in Redis worldwide, I started to collect informations to move on, I have my own application case similar to weather recording applications represented as follows in SQL DB:

```
(cityID, sensorID, StartReadingTime, EndReadingTime, AverageValue)
```

Each city `(cityID)` has many sensors `(sensorID)` which reading the values of temperature.

I have composite key on `(cityID,SensorID,StartReadingTime)`.

My first question is: what is the best way to represent my case in Redis and how? 
Hashes, Lists, sets …etc

As I read in many articles, that before storing the data in Redis, I have to figure out how I want to get it back  later, in other world, what queries I will run to retrieve the data.

I have three main queries for my case

1- Basic selection (Key lookup)

```
 SELECT *  
 FROM weather  
 WHERE cityID = ?  
 AND sensorID=  ? 
 AND  StartReadingTime = ? ;
```

2- Range search

```
SELECT  *  
FROM weather 
WHERE AverageValue > ? 
AND AverageValue < ?
```

3- Aggregation with range search

```
 SELECT  count(*)  
 FROM weather 
 WHERE AverageValue > ? 
 AND AverageValue < ?
```

I will be appreciate if you can give me hints and guides for my case, that will encourage me to continue starting with Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that each query may need a different data structure to answer optimally. In your case, you'll need to maintain two data structures.

> 1- Basic selection (Key lookup)

Keep the readings in Hashes like so:

- Key name: `<city>:<sensor>`
- Field name: `<start>`
- Field value: `:
- Query: `HGET <city>:<sensor> <start>` and split the value on `:`

> 2- Range search

Keep the readings in Sorted Sets like so:

- Key name: `averages`
- Member score: `<avg>`
- Member value: `<city>:<sensor>:<start>:<end>`
- Query: `ZRANGEBYSCORE averages <from avg> <to avg> and split the value on`:`

> 3- Aggregation with range search

The same logic as 2, but since you don't actually need the values just the count, you can save some network in the query with a Lua snippet such as this one:

```
EVAL "local r = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) return #r" 1 averages <from avg> <to avg)
```